# Where did the T in wchar_t come from?

Tags: c++, c, terminology, etymology

In many native types, a common suffix (and sometimes prefix) of `t` or `_t` is used to denote platform-independent types (such as `wchar_t`, `int32_t`, etc.)

What was the logic behind the letter `t` as opposed to other letters (or none at all, especially in the case of `wchar_t`)? Does it stand for something?

Comment: Just guessing, but what about "type"?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Good guess; that would make sense.

Comment: [Duplicate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231760/what-does-a-type-followed-by-t-underscore-t-represent)

Comment: @Lundin Not really; that question is asking what types with `_t` are for. I already know what they are for; I was asking where the `t` itself came from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As opposed to _s which commonly denotes C structs I always envisioned _t to stand for typedefs.

Comment: so it's a form of hungarian notation?

Comment: @MattDavey: yes. A very rudimentary form, but yes. And it's mostly used because typenames and identifiers live in the same namespace in C and C++.